# What are the UniqueIdentifier values used for in the .vcxproj.filters files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a Visual C++ 10 (VS2010) .vcxproj project file and I want to copy it and use the copy in the same solution file as the original project.

I understand that I need to generate a new ProjectGuid in the new .vcxproj file, but I don't know what edits I would need to make to the .vcxproj.filters file.

In the .vcxproj.filters file, I see that there are many UniqueIdentifier elements which have GUIDs for values. I assume that I would need to re-generate all of these in the new .vcxproj.filters, but Visual Studio didn't report any errors and didn't seem to have any problems with having the same GUIDs in two different .vcxproj.filters files in the same solution file.

Does anyone know if it is safe to have duplicate UniqueIdentifiers across different .vcxproj.filters files in the same solution file? Does anyone know what these UniqueIdentifiers are for?

Is there an easier way of making a duplicate of a .vcxproj / .vcxproj.filters pair without having to regenerate every single GUID used in the .vcxproj.filters file?

Comment: This question is 4 years old now. Has anyone found more information about this?

Comment: I don't have an answer regarding the file format of the *.vcxproj.filters files. However, there is an easier way to copy/reconstruct project files: Have a tool generate the project/solution files for you. For example, [CMake](https://cmake.org/) has support for Visual Studio. As far as I know, it doesn't (or doesn't easily) support generation of *.vcxproj.filters files, though. The project's file structure is the same as the on-disk directory hierarchy.

Comment: Or you can, from within the VS IDE, just choose `Tools | Create GUID`, choose registry format, and just copy it to the clipboard, pasting it back into your project file.

Comment: At least with VS2010 and VS2019, I've been able to just copy a project to a new name in the solution folder, make some name changes and add the project to the solution from within VS.  So I end up with a few projects with all the same IDs.  That has not effected my solution in any adverse way, that I know of.  
I went to do the same thing today (10/2022) and decided to at least modify the IDs, after first searching for the "right way" to do this.  Would be nice if someone found the correct answer and posted that, after 10 years!